# activity as dialog in android

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I want to use an **`activity as dialog`** and i made the theme of the activity as dialog & i succeed.
but
i have the problem here is when i click outside of the activity 
its automatically get closed & the previous activity get started..

i tried a thing to make transparent  parent layout it does not look like a dialog..

i want to use this activity to create new account in my application as it has only 3 fields so in tablet it looks large space unused... so i want to use activity as dialog.....

thenx in advance...!!!
examples will be appreciated..!!!!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try with following property

```
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 7):

Make change in code as per your need.

Thanks

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RlayMain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtsignin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="SIGN IN"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtUserName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtsignin"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtuser"
                android:hint="USERNAME" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtUserName"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="PASSWORD"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtPassword"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Sign In" >
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnSignIn"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Sign Up For Free!" >
            </Button>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I should point out for those who use this, that while using _sp_ is best for measuring font-sizes, _dp_ is (typically) best for things such as layout spacing and should be used to measure your margins - **not** _sp_.

Answer (score 3):

if you haven't already tried it, then this is the way to achieve activity as dialog: 
in your manifest file, add to your activity the following attribute:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MyActivityName"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: this is working..
activity worked as dialog but when i click outside that dialog its get automatically closed......

Comment: try add the following attribute:      android:configChanges="orientation"   when I'm trying it myself inside my own application - it's not closing the dialogActivity when I'm touching outside

Answer (score 2):

to Start activity as dialog I defined:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Now when I `startActivity()` it displays like a dialog and parent activity displays behind it. I want a Button which when clicked Dialog gets dismissed and parent activity should display without refreshing the page.

Create an activity as we usually create it.

Also check [CustomDialogActivity.java on android.com](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomDialogActivity.html)

I think you should create activity as a dialog, it helps.

This way, you can set style and theme for your activity.

Answer (score 2):

For the issue of avoiding closing the activity when clicking outside window
from API 11 
as mentioned by Vivek use this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

but for prior APIs use this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&  isOutOfBounds(this, event)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private boolean isOutOfBounds(Activity context, MotionEvent event) {
    final int x = (int) event.getX();
    final int y = (int) event.getY();
    final int slop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledWindowTouchSlop();
    final View decorView = context.getWindow().getDecorView();
    return (x < -slop) || (y < -slop)
            || (x > (decorView.getWidth()+slop))
            || (y > (decorView.getHeight()+slop));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Same Activity in Mobile devices and Tablets.

**Mobile :-**

1. Goto res -> values.
2. Open styles.xml and add following theme settings.

styles.xml :-

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**Tablet :-** Launch activity as dialog.

1. Goto "res".
2. Create new folder "values-sw720dp".
3. Create new styles.xml and add following theme settings.

styles.xml :-

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_green_800</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/material_green_800</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMajor">800dp</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMinor">800dp</item>
</style>
```

Manifest.xml :-

```
    <activity
    android:name=".LogInActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_log_in"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"            //set the theme activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
```