# How to prevent theme.dialog activity to allow outside touch?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that is using the Theme.Dialog style. It's a popup for my quiz game, for the wrong answer. But I have a problem. User can click outside the popup dialog themed activity and click on the next question. How to prevent that? I blocked back button and that works fine.
Also, when a user clicks on the popup or outside of it, it starts counting the ON time again. My popup stays ON for 2500 ms. How to prevent that also?

So, basically I don't want to allow any click outside my popup and don't want to reset my delay time when someone clicks on the screen.

Here's the code of the popup window:

```
public class WrongAnswer extends Activity{
    MediaPlayer sound;
    TextView wrong;
    String correctAnswer, correct;

    public final int delayTime = 2500;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    public void onUserInteraction(){
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(closePopup);
        myHandler.postDelayed(closePopup, delayTime);
    }
    private Runnable zatvoriPopup = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            finish();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.wrong);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras !=null) {
           tacno = extras.getString("correctAnswer");
        }

        inicijalizujVarijable();

        myHandler.postDelayed(closePopup, delayTime);


            }

    private void inicijalizujVarijable() {
        wrong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWrong);
        wrong.setText("Wrong answer!\nCorrect answer is:\n\n" + correct);
    }
    }
```

My activity in manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.myquiz.myquizgame.WrongAnswer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.myquiz.myquizgame.WRONGANSWER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I got you correctly, this question had been already asked. Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987794/1824898), and according to it you need to call a setter method on activity, that will close your activity dialog:

```
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

I hope it will help you.

Second, every time when user touches WrongAnswer activity — you start new delayed task and cancel previous one here:

```
public void onUserInteraction() {
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(zatvoriPopup);
    myHandler.postDelayed(zatvoriPopup, delayTime);
}
```

that's why you have problems with timer

Comment: This still does not help me. I have no problem with cancelling the activity. I need everything outside my popup not to be clickable.

Comment: Do you need that dialog to be modal?

Comment: And more: what is the purpose of the dialog? To punish user for wrong answer and force him to wait some time, until dialog will close itself automatically?

Comment: OK, your code actually did the trick. It does not allow clicks outside the popup now, but I still have the problem, cause once the user clicks anywhere, delayTime starts to count again, and instead of 2500ms, you get 5000ms, if you clicks once. 7500ms if you click twice.

Comment: Look, as I told you, your first answer worked. Buttons don't get clicked. It's much simplier. But I have that other problem, with delayTime. Here's my popup how it looks, just to paint you some picture in your head: http://i.imgur.com/a7mIOXZ.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58917/discussion-between---and-marjanbaz).

Comment: this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false); is working fine